# Could saying-no be made a synonym of boundaries?

Tags: discussion, tags

[saying-no](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying-no) questions are basically questions about how to set a boundary (i.e. how to set a boundary by saying no). But a [boundaries](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundaries) tag already exists!

Could [saying-no](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying-no) be made a synonym of [boundaries](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundaries)? Or since there aren't any mods yet, could you just remove [saying-no](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying-no) from questions and replace it with [boundaries](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundaries)? And can we get some mods appointed? Like yesterday?

---

In response to comments from chat:

1. If a question is about saying no to a request that you do not want to honor (e.g. How can I say no to a friend who wants me to do something risky), then use [tag: boundaries].
2. If a question is about how to decline a request politely, use [politeness](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politeness).
3. If a question is about both, use both [boundaries](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundaries) and [politeness](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politeness).

Don't use [saying-no](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying-no).

Comment: Personally, I feel that "saying no" is a subset of setting boundaries, but I'm not sure if I would merge those tags. I think the tag just needs to be renamed into something more appropriate, but I don't know what I would rename it to.

Comment: @Zizouz212 well, sure, it's a subset. But tags are supposed to help people find questions that they can answer. Is there anyone who would only be interested in answering questions about saying no, but not questions about setting boundaries? I doubt it.

Comment: I'm just looking through the questions, and just by looking at the titles, but it's more like declining offers of things. Boundaries is about saying what is and what is not acceptable for situations, so there's a bit of a clash for me there.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are also meant to be combined, and be used to filter questions out. As mentioned in comments, [saying-no](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying-no) is a subset of [boundaries](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundaries)

In much the same way that on Stack Overflow [jquery](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery) is a subset of [javascript](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Questions that are purely about boundaries, without saying no, will fit into the broader category of [boundaries](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundaries) exclusively, while questions about saying no specifically could use both.

Essentially, a user could be interested in questions about boundaries and not be interested in continuing to explain how to say no for the hundredth time, in much the same way that vanilla JavaScript experts get tired of explaining jQuery to people.

It may sound crazy to you that not all [boundaries](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundaries) questions are about [saying-no](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying-no)  in much the same way that some jQuery users don't understand that not all JavaScript questions are about jQuery. Some day a [boundaries](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundaries) question may be about [saying-yes](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying-yes)

Unfortunately the analogy continues to hold up... While some users may be really good at saying-no, they may not have a good grip on boundaries without saying-no... In much the same way that some users may be proficient in jQuery without knowing much about JavaScript.

Comment: Tags are to help people find questions to answer. Why would someone only be interested in saying no questions but not boundaries questions? Contrast that to javascript and jquery on Stack Overflow, where there are programmers who know one but not the other.

Comment: "It may sound crazy to you that not all boundaries questions are about saying-no in much the same way that some jQuery users don't understand that not all JavaScript questions are about jQuery." Could you explain why? And/or give examples of such questions?

Comment: @Hamlet we don't have a lot of examples to work with thus far, but I don't have a hard time imagining a person who wants to lower some of their boundaries or perhaps someone who wants to set boundaries before they even need to tell someone no.